# Regular expression to match specified substring to end of string?

Tags: regex

What regular expression will match everything including a specified substring to the end of the string?

For example, in

```
"now is the time for (all) good men"
```

I want to match the substring:

```
"for (all) good men"
```

I know the specific sub-substring "for" that begins what I want to match; I don't know what's after it.

Comment: I don't know how nsregularexpression differs from other implementations, but try [`for all(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/sZ0yV0/2) to match and capture anything after "for all", up to the end of a line. Click the link to see it / test it on regex101.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking to match everything from the given string to the end of the line.

You need to match anything following the search string, using . to match anything, and * to tell the regex to expect any number of anythings, including 0.

So, your regex should read something like

```
/\(for all) good men.*/
```

The forward slash before the first bracket is necessary in this case because the bracket is reserved in regex -- that is, it means something -- the forward slash escapes it so that it is treated as a normal character.

The slashes on either end of the pattern are standard practice. You wouldn't need them in java, but you would in javascript, sed, vi, and other implementations.

If you're asking how to match the given string only if it is at the end of the line then you'd use this:

```
/\(for all) good men$/
```

Where the `$` means end-of-line.

Comment: Where in your answer did you use the "." to match anything? Note also my edited version of the question: I know a sub-substring that begins the substring I want to match, but do not know what might follow it.